# Comparing a text box's input to a variable

Tags: c#, .net

My program requires users to input answers into a text box to randomly generated questions. The questions have calculated answers which are stored in variables. Comparing the text box's input with that variable doesn't work properly, hence why I'm here.

```
enum elements { lithium, beryllium, sodium, magnesium };

public void Moles()
    {
        string elementName;
        int elementsLength = Enum.GetNames(typeof(elements)).Length;          
        double moles, mass, roundedMoles, Mr = 0;

        Random random = new Random();
        elementName = (Enum.GetNames(typeof(elements))[random.Next(0, elementsLength)]);
        mass = random.Next(1, 100);

        switch (elementName)
        {
            case "lithium":
                Mr = 7;
                break;
            case "beryllium":
                Mr = 9;
                break;
            case "sodium":
                Mr = 23;
                break;
            case "magnesium":
                Mr = 24;
                break;
        }

        moles = mass / Mr;
        roundedMoles = Math.Round(moles);

        label1.Text = ("How many moles in " + mass + "g" + " of " + elementName + "?");
        string input = textBox1.Text.ToString();

        if (input == roundedMoles.ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Good");
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bad");
            textBox1.Clear();
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Moles();
    }
```

As you can see, the program will calculate a number of moles and round it to the nearest whole number. It's then stored in a variable, 'roundedMoles' - this variable is what's compared with the text box's input.

However, the message box will randomly show 'Good' or 'Bad' regardless of whether the input is correct or not. Bear in mind that this code works fine in a console application, so I don't know whether it's something I'm doing wrong or if it just doesn't want to work.

Sorry if this code isn't of a high standard. I'm not that good at programming.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and checking the values of your calculation and your input?

Comment: Also my first guess is white space issues. Call Trim() on your user input to ensure it doesn't have trailing or leading whitespace

Comment: Hello @Dave mate. I actually have 3 labels on my main form which show the mass, the Mr and the calculated moles (which are all correct). Even if I enter the moles, it still says 'Bad'.

Comment: Can you please show any example so that we can see when it is not working? Btw i don't see any major problem in your code.

Comment: Just to clarify as well as I think it makes a big difference to finding an answer. If you enter the WRONG answer it sometimes says 'Good'?

Comment: Did you read the definition of [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round)? Especially the part about Midpoint values? My guess is it isn't rounding the way you think it does.

Comment: I've programmed it to round to the nearest whole number, which it's doing fine. And yes @Dave, it doesn't matter what I enter, it'll randomly alternate between 'Good' and 'Bad'. I can even submit a blank answer and it'll sometimes say 'Good'

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of outputting `Good` or `Bad`, why don't you output the values of the textbox and `roundedMoles`? It will be easier to see what the difference is.

Comment: Good point by Jurgen. Also store your double to string value in a variable and compare the variable with your input variable. Put a breakpoint on the comparison line and look at the two variable values in the debugger

Comment: Hi all. I added a line that converts `roundedMoles` into a string, and set a breakpoint on that line. Apparently, the string is null at the breakpoint. Will investigate further...

Comment: I've been looking at breakpoints and I've noticed something strange. It seems to be getting the next question's moles and comparing it with the current question's input, so the input will always be wrong.

Comment: Ok I've got a theory but I need to check it so I'm just getting my laptop running to try it out. Are you sure you don't get this problem doing this as a console app?

Comment: @Dave, yeah I'm sure it doesn't happen on the console. I have the Forms version and the console version open right now. The console version works as expected. Heck, I could do my entire project on console but that's not what college wants...

Comment: ok my theory is now out of the window. But I'll keep fiddling..this has intrigued me

Comment: Can you post a link to your console code in dotnet fiddle or code bin or something like that?

Comment: Ok stay with me here. Your forms app I'm going walk through me using it (I've copied your code exactly and created a form that has the neccessary elemetns).

1. The form loads the label reads nothing.
2. I press the button.
3. The label now has the question in it and I get a pop box saying bad.
4. I answer the question 
5. I get good or bad.

The reason is that you set the label as the questions and then immediately capture the value of the text box. The text box value i typed with either an old question in it or no question in it. You need a button that gets a question and shows it...

Comment: and then another button that accepts me answer

Comment: @Dave, so if I read correctly, I need to have two buttons: one to answer the question, and one that gets a question?

Comment: Maybe not 'need' but it should solve your problem. The reason the console version works is it prints the question then asks for input. The forms version is changing the label and then immediately capturing the text box value

Comment: Thank you @Dave. I shall now test it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the answer...

The reason the console works is that you write to the console to ask the question. You then do console.Readline() this captures the input of the answer after they have seen the question.

On the forms version. You set the label to the question and immediately capture the text box value. The user has not had a chance to enter the answer, or its still the answer from the last time (hence why it randomly goes from "Good" to "Bad" because sometimes the answer is the same).

One simple way is make your variables at the top of the Moles() method, class variables on the form and then have 2 buttons with 2 methods one that gets the questions and sets your answer variables and then a second button then the user can press when they've entered their answer.

Check out this code paste https://www.pastebucket.com/564406

(You'll need button2 added to your form for this to work obviously)

edit: I've done a quick cut and paste of code there. You shouldn't just copy this and use it. Look what I've done and apply it properly and try and understand why it works

Comment: Absolute life saver! Thanks a bunch. You've saved me hours of headaches down the line of this project. I did something similar to you which didn't work. But I understand what you did.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

### Don't compare strings as numbers

When comparing numeric values, never compare string to string. Always convert to a numeric variable. Otherwise, "0.00" will not equal "0" and "1234 " (with a space at the end) won't equal "1234" (with no space). Also, you will run into serious trouble if you're working with a culture that uses `,` as the decimal point.

So, instead of this:

```
string input = textBox1.Text.ToString();
if (input == roundedMoles.ToString())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Good");
    textBox1.Clear();
```

Use something like this:

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
double inputAsDouble;
bool ok = double.tryParse(out inputAsDouble);
if (!ok)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value.");
    return;
}
if (inputAsDouble == roundedMoles)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Good");
    textBox1.Clear();
```

### Don't compare floating point values as exact

When comparing floating point values, don't use `==`. Instead, compute the difference and make sure it is below a certain tolerance. You have to do this because floating point variables are only approximations.

So instead of

```
if (inputAsDouble == roundedMoles)
```

use

```
const double Tolerance = 0.00001;
if (inputAsDouble - roundedMoles < Tolerance)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might have a culture related problem down there. Always be careful when comparing `Double` values converted to `String`. The framework might be converting '1,5' to '1.5' depending on your regional settings.
The first thing I would recomend you is not to compare as `String` but do it as `Double`. And if you do that, ensure that you will replace dots with comma or other way.

```
    if (Convert.ToDouble(input) == roundedMoles)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Good");
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bad");
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Hello @NicoRiff mate. Doing this hasn't improved anything unfortunately. I'm not sure what I can do.